# Can a minor request a copy of a contract parents signed on their behalf?

Tags: contract-law, australia, minor

Can a minor get a copy of a contract parents signed on their behalf and if so, how can the minor get it (in New South Wales, Australia)?

Comment: This is awfully broad: *Any contract?*  And does "[NSW]" mean you're interested in the jurisdiction of New South Wales, Australia?

Comment: My thought exactly. NSW stands for "Not Safe For Work" and "New South Wales" (and probably for other things as well). Also what is meant by the phrase "share can they get it"? Is "how can they get it?" what was meant?

Comment: I have revised it making reasonable assumptions.